# How can i configure an existing App Service to have a static IP address .. not to a VM?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to associate a reserved/static  IP with an App Service and NOT with a VM.

So i have tried to use Powershell commands to achieve this , but no success.
What i have used is

New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName  –Location "UK West" -ServiceName 
Get-azureservice -servicename

Both have been unsuccessful.
Can i actually do this ?
Also will this change the Inbound and Outbound Ip addresses ?
So will only the static IP need to be whitelisted on client firewalls ?

UPDATE:

1. Go to the Azure portal and navigate to your App Service.
2. Click on "Configuration" from the App Service menu.
3. Scroll down to the "General settings" section and click on "Networking".
4. In the "Networking" section, click on "Configure IP Address".
5. In the "Configure IP Address" dialog box, select "Static" as the IP address type.
6. Enter the IP address that you want to assign to the App Service in the "IP Address" field.
7. Enter the subnet mask for the IP address in the "Subnet Mask" field.
8. Click on "Save" to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done, not sure if you require the powershell commands to do this but I'm going to give you the portal way of doing this as this is how I know to do it.

1. Navigate to your app service
2. Click on the networking tab
3. Click "Configure IP"
4. Select static IP address from the dropdown and enter your IP address

Also I'm not sure on your exact setup but you would need to associate it to a subnet and a vnet. To your second question, yes this will affect your inbound and outbound rules so you will need to add them onto a NSG on the vnet you associating the app to as well as your client firewall when they connecting over the internet

Update: As you can see below I have a function app using my app service plan. If I go onto my function app I will find networking options.

[image]

Clicking on networking gives me the "Vnet Integration" (outbound traffic) and private endpoint (configure private inbound traffic)

[image]
[image]

Hopefully this helps

Comment: There is no option "Configure IP" all there is   Inbound Address,  Domains , Features, Outbound networking features and Inbound networking features ?

Comment: Also do clients need to whitelist the inboud or outbound address ?

Comment: On their firewall they would need to whitelist outbound and on your app service you white list them as inbound

Comment: Ok but There is no option "Configure IP" in Azure for the app service ?

Comment: What app is connected to the app service? Azure function app or web app? You would need to go into your app thats using that app service and you will find the option there

Comment: It is a web app . When you say app service , do you mean the app service plan ? Do you have pics to illustrate the process ?

Comment: I have gone into the  web app and there isnt that option. Has it been moved elsewhere in the Azure portal ?

Comment: I have updated the answer and included screenshots.

Comment: thankyou so much i will have a look

Comment: I am wanting to do this for a web app service . Also I have had a quick look and VNet Integration is off

Comment: They would be the samething, no matter what you host it will use a azure app service and they would have the same options. I do know that vnet integration and private endpoints are only supported on the premium plans and above.

Comment: Networking options - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-security, plans - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans

Comment: Im not sure how this solev my issue. All i am looking for is to give a .net app service a static ip address for clients to whitelist. , instead of having to whitelist all the addresses in the outbound traffic under networking for the app service ?

Comment: Yes and what I am reiterating to you is that no matter the app, app service will allow this (whether function or web app). You will have a list of outbound ip addresses and a static inbound ip address that your dns will resolve to. Here is the official ms doc explaining this and might help guide you in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips

Comment: I have put some steps i tried to follow in the question as an update:
 But the issue is in step 4 there is no "Configure IP Address" , it only has the inbound and outbound addresses

Comment: what app service plan are you using? can you maybe add more info about what you seeing and what the resources look like? (dont forget to block any personal information)

Comment: The app service plan is B2 Basic Plan 2. What i amn seeing is what you have in the images above

Comment: Okay I dont think the basic plans have any network capabilities and is not recommended for production use. Please try upgrading to standard and see if networking options show up